# Is there a way to alias types in Haxe when compiling to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, types, alias, haxe

I have the following two classes:

```
package geometer;

class Vector2Impl {
  public var x: Float;
  public var y: Float;

  ... operations and methods...
```

```
package geometer;

@:forward(x, y)
abstract Vector2(Vector2Impl) from Vector2Impl to Vector2Impl {
  public
  function new(x: Float, y: Float) {
    this = new Vector2Impl(x, y);
  }

  ... operator overloads ...
}
```

I did this so I could overload operators in `Vector2`. This all works fine from inside of Haxe, however, we compile from Haxe to JavaScript. Our output JavaScript is then used in mocha tests.

Unfortunately, classes declared `abstract` are completely omitted from the JS code (well, this isn't *entirely* true, but they do look something like:

```
var geometer__$Vector2_Vector2_$Impl_$ = {};
geometer__$Vector2_Vector2_$Impl_$.__name__ = true;
geometer__$Vector2_Vector2_$Impl_$._new = function(x,y) {
    return new geometer_Vector2Impl(x,y);
};
```

So, in my tests, instead of using `Vector2`, I am forced to use `Vector2Impl`. This is a bit of a pain, because a) it requires more typing, and b) it exposes an inconsistent interface between Haxe clients and JavaScript clients. I could deal with it, but since Haxe isn't completely compiling out the type `Vector2`, I'm wondering if there is a way I can alias `Vector2Impl` to `Vector2` inside of the generated `.js` file. That way, instead of doing the following in my tests:

```
'use strict';

let expect = require('chai').expect;
let library = require('../../dist/library.js');
let geometer = library.geometer;

// Unfortunately, abstract classes (Vector2) are not available in JS-land.
let Vector2Impl = geometer.Vector2Impl;

require('../nyc-reporter');

describe('Vector2Impl', function() {
  describe ('#new', function() {
    it ('should create a new Vector2Impl object', function() {
      let v = new Vector2Impl(20.5, 100.0);

      expect(v.x).to.eq(20.5);
      expect(v.y).to.eq(100.0);
    });
  });
});
```

I could do this:

```
'use strict';

let expect = require('chai').expect;
let library = require('../../dist/library.js');
let geometer = library.geometer;

// Unfortunately, abstract classes (Vector2) are not available in JS-land.
let Vector2 = geometer.Vector2;

require('../nyc-reporter');

describe('Vector2', function() {
  describe ('#new', function() {
    it ('should create a new Vector2 object', function() {
      let v = new Vector2(20.5, 100.0);

      expect(v.x).to.eq(20.5);
      expect(v.y).to.eq(100.0);
    });
  });
});
```

Obviously, I know that I can't use the operator overloads in JavaScript, since the language doesn't support it, but if I could use all the other methods available in `Vector2Impl` by calling it `Vector2`, that would be awesome.

**NOTE**: I know I could just do this:

```
let Vector2 = geometer.Vector2Impl;
```

But, I'd rather the client not even be aware of the `Vector2Impl` class, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply annotate `Vector2DImpl` with [`@:expose` metadata](https://haxe.org/manual/target-javascript-expose.html):

```
@:expose("geometer.Vector2D")
class Vector2Impl {
    ...
}
```

This includes it in `$hx_exports` as `geometer.Vector2D`.